# lxpanelctl not working!

Tags: 12.10, lxde, lxpanel

lxpanelctl does nothing! Either when I launch it with the keyboard shortcut or from terminal.

When I enter lxpanelctl menu or lxpanelctl run in the terminal window, nothing happens. The case is the same when I use the respective keyboard shortcut.

What could be wrong? How can I set it right?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's already reported and discussed at launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxpanel/+bug/769644

> Vedran Rodic (vrodic) wrote on 2013-09-04:
>
> This has been fixed very recently in current lxpanel git: http://lxde.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=lxde/lxpanel;a=commit;h=0f83fb71915fd7c87a999ebe83e41b2d033e4340
> Hopefully we'll have this soon in ubuntu.